# How to resolve the file path too long issue on windows by using Python 3? (tried other methods on this platform)

Tags: python, windows, path, long-integer, shutil

I was using the code `shutil.copyfile(src_file, dst_file)` to copy the source file into the target destination. However, the path is apparently too long, so I got the error `'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: .\\Merged\\Book\\Book123\\New\\library\\helloworld\\ass\\data\\explore_the_world\\explore_content\\sassy_pane\\conditional_testing\\formatting_life_session\\locales\\en\\conditional_fformatting_life_session_component_new.strings.json'`

I think the double slash was built into the Python file path interpretation, so I can't just change it from my script.. I've read the method of adding `u(\\\\?\)` to the file path, such as `shutil.copyfile(u"\\\\?\\" + src_file, u"\\\\?\\" + dst_file)`, but it doesn't work.. I'll get an error of `'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: \\\\?\\.\\Merged\\Book\\Book123\\New\\library\\helloworld\\ass\\data\\explore_the_world\\explore_content\\sassy_pane\\conditional_testing\\formatting_life_session\\locales\\en\\conditional_fformatting_life_session_component_new.strings.json'`

I've read this article, but it doesn't really help solve my issue..Could anybody enlighten me over this? Thank you!! 
[Python: copy long file path Shutil.copyfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046509/python-copy-long-file-path-shutil-copyfile)

Comment: I thought "\\\\?\" would only work with absolute paths?

Comment: "\\\\"????,you can use `r'c:\xx\xxx\xxxx\'` or just `r'c:/xx/xxx/xxxx/'`